# How to import/load ng-bootstrap to angular5 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Why I can't load ng-bootstrap on my angular project ? does anyone experience the same thing ?

Thank you in advance

this is app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: From the image you included, it looks like you are able to install it, you have the same version as here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home, so you have to clarify your question, otherwise you will get too many down votes

Comment: after install finish, i try to write the code, then the bootstrap can't show.

Comment: You have to include your code, and errors you have, people cannot figure out what you have.

Comment: okay i re upload image my problem

Comment: you have to include source code, not as images. Look at other questions asked in this site.

Comment: like that @HDJEMAI , sorry i am new in stackoverflow

Comment: Did you also install [Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/), and imported it in your project (for example, with `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";` in vendor.ts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Judging from your code, you may have missed the `NgbModule.forRoot()` in the imports array in app.module.ts**

In order to get ng-bootstrap to work in Angular, you have to do the following things:

1. Install Bootstrap `npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2`
2. Import Bootstrap into either

   - styles.css using `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`, or
   - .angular-cli.json via the styles property:

     `"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     ],`
3. Install ng-bootstrap `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
4. Import the ng-boostrap module into app.module.ts:

   `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

   `@NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
     imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule {
   }`

The install process is well documented in [ng-boostrap's Getting Started Page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)